Displaying selected dropdown items in specified order
I am working on a React application and I want to build a dropdown where the user can select the working days of the employee.
I have implemented a custom React element with NextUI, which maps the following array as SelectItem options:
const workingDaysOptions = ["Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday"] 

const [selectedWorkingDaysOptions, setSelectedWorkingDaysOptions] = useState([]);

 const handleSelection = () => {
     setSelectedWorkingDaysOptions();
 }

The custom element:
const CustomSelect = ({classAttributes, label, placeholder, selectionMode, selectedKeys, onSelectionChange, mappedArray, isRequired}) => {

    return(
        <Select
            className={classAttributes}
            label={label}
            placeholder={placeholder}
            selectionMode={selectionMode}
            selectedKeys={selectedKeys}
            onSelectionChange={onSelectionChange}
            isRequired={isRequired}
            >
            {mappedArray.map((option) => (
                <SelectItem key={option} value={option}>
                    {option}
                </SelectItem>
            ))}
        </Select>

    )
}

The elements are displayed automatically next to each other in the order of the selection, separated with comma. What I want to implement is to check the index of the selected day in the workingDaysOptions array, and order the days in the selectedWorkingDaysOptions accordingly.
Example: If the user selects "Tuesday", "Friday", "Monday" then it should be displayed as "Monday", "Tuesday", "Friday"
I have tried options like a strict order defined in an object, but in this way the selection does not happen.
    const workingDaySorter = {
        "monday": 1,
        "tuesday": 2,
        "wednesday": 3,
        "thursday": 4,
        "friday": 5,
        "saturday": 6,
        "sunday": 7
      }


    const handleSelection = () => {
        selectedWorkingDaysOptions.sort(function (a, b) {
            const day1 = a.toLowerCase();
            const day2 = b.toLowerCase();
            return workingDaySorter[day1] - workingDaySorter[day2];
        });
        setSelectedWorkingDaysOptions(selectedWorkingDaysOptions);
        
    };


If you're keeping the selected values in state, you could create the options array as the currently selected values plus the remaining values.
For example
const [selection, setSelection] = useState<readonly string[]>([])

{[...selection,... workingDaysOptions.filter(v=>selection.includes(v))].map((option) => (...


And then if when you handle the selection, you add it to the start of the array it should work as intended.
setSelection(current=>[value,...setSelection])

Edit:
Think I misunderstood what you were looking for in terms of order, thought you meant reverse the selection order.
If you want to order them by days of the week, you could just create the new array of values, then sort that
setSelection((current) => {
  const next = [...current, value];
  return next.sort(function (a, b) {
    const day1 = a.toLowerCase();
    const day2 = b.toLowerCase();
    return workingDaySorter[day1] - workingDaySorter[day2];
  });
});

